# check empty edit text in an alert dialog android

Tags: java, android, while-loop, android-edittext

I have the following code for checking empty edit text in an alert dialog, but it is not working

```
    if (mPhoneNumber == null) {
        mPhoneNumber = GetNumber();
        if (mPhoneNumber == "Error") {

            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Warrning");
            alert.setMessage("Please Set Your Phone number");
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {
                            String value = input.getText().toString();
                            while (value.isEmpty())
                            {
                                alert.setTitle("Warrning");
                                alert.setMessage("Please Set Your Phone number");
                                alert.setView(input);
                                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {
                                                String value = input.getText().toString();}});
                            }
                            String Result = SetNumber(value);
                            mPhoneNumber = value;
                            int UserServiceId = CallLogin(mPhoneNumber);
                            if (UserServiceId > 0) {
                                Intent Service = new Intent(MainScreeen.this,
                                        RecipeService.class);
                                Service.putExtra("UserId", UserServiceId);
                                startService(Service);
                            } else {
                                Intent Reg = new Intent(MainScreeen.this,Regsteration.class);
                                Reg.putExtra("PhoneNumber", mPhoneNumber);
                                startActivity(Reg);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
```

I need to enforce the user to inter his/her phone number and not leaving the edit text being empty, I used a while loop but it is not working

Comment: Define "it is not working". What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: `if(mPhoneNumber == "Error")`. Write in google "Comparing strings in Java".

Comment: The same reason than the next StackOverflow question [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952446/checking-if-edittext-isempty-not-working/27952746#27952746

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to compare `String` values. You can't do it like this

```
if (mPhoneNumber == "Error")
```

change that to

```
if("Error".equals(mPhoneNumber))
```

`==` compares if they are the same object for `Strings` but not if they have the same value. Doing it this way you shouldn't need the `null` check because "Error" won't equal `mPhoneNumber` if `mPhoneNumber` is `null`

Comment: all of the code works fine except for the while loop part, looks like the program goes into an infinite loop... I want the alert dialog to show up as long as the user press "ok" without entering a value

Comment: Then why need a loop? Just show the `Dialog` every time the user presses the `Button` and the `EditText` is empty. How are they going to enter something with a dialog there. Close it and allow them to enter whatever it is. Also, you still need to change the comparison as in my answer

Comment: If they are entering it into the dialog then just have the button run the code `if` it isn't empty `else` do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a while loop, why don't you make your `AlertDialog` building a separate method and call that method, then in the `onClick` of your `AlertDialog` button use an if else to check if that value is empty and if it is make a recursive call on your `AlertDialog` method.