# Checking if EditText.isEmpty() not working

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, is-empty

In my code, I want to check if the password field `is empty`. I am using the `isEmpty()` method to accomplish it but it does not work. Leaving the `password` field blank, reverts to the 2nd else-if statement and not the third.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Password);
    Button enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    enter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String user_pass;
            user_pass = password.getText().toString();

                if (user_pass.equals("123")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent I = new Intent("com.mavenmaverick.password.OKActivity");
                    startActivity(I);
                }

                else

                    if(user_pass != "123"){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Oops!");
                        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Incorrect Password");
                        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        dialogBuilder.show();
                    }

                else
                    if (user_pass.isEmpty()) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Oops!");
                            dialogBuilder.setMessage("Password Field Cannot Be Empty");
                            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                            dialogBuilder.show();
                        }

        }
    });




}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your second if checks for `user_pass != "123"`. Logically, if the `user_pass` is empty it is not `"123"` and it won't even go for the third if. If you want it to work, switch your second and third if.

Comment: `user_pass != "123"` is not correct.  It must be `!user_pass.equals("123")`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string == "aString") {
    ...
} else if (string != "somestring") {
    ...
} else if (string.isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

This won't check if the string is empty, it will stop on the 2nd if block since it's not equal.

To avoid this, check if it's empty first. Also **don't** use `==` when comparing string values:

```
if (user_pass.isEmpty()) {
    // It's empty
} else if (user_pass.equals("123")) {
    // Equals
} else if (!user_pass.equals("123")){
    // Not equals
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong String comparison with operators. For string comparison, you can use `.equals()` method.

By the way for your case,

just use,

```
if (user_pass.isEmpty()) {
      displayAlertDialog("Password Field Cannot Be Empty");
}else if(user_pass.equals("123"))
{
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Intent I = new Intent("com.mavenmaverick.password.OKActivity");
 startActivity(I);

}else
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    displayAlertDialog("Incorrect Password");               
}

private void displayAlertDialog(String message)
{
 AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Oops!");
                            dialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
                            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                            dialogBuilder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if(user_pass != "123"){**

You are checking directly the **memoy position**, which is always **false**.

Use  **if(!user_pass.equals("123")){** instead of.